# Does frame dependency of events result in entirely different worlds?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, inertial-frames, observers

Suppose there are two seeds kept at equal distance from a light source which emits a photon each on either directions. Seed germinates when a photon falls on it. According to rest frame both the seeds receive photons simultaneously but according to moving frame one of the seeds receive a photon earlier than the other seed. The second seed dies off due to delay, so there is only one plant in the moving frame but two plants in the rest frame. Is my line of reasoning correct?
What happens when I bring the moving observer to rest so that he should agree with whatever observations made by the observer who was at rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your reasoning is based on a misunderstanding. There is only one reality. Observers in two different frames will assign different time coordinates to exactly the same events. In every frame, the two seeds will germinate and survive, but one seed might germinate at an earlier or later time coordinate than the other, depending on the direction of motion of the frame.

You will find, if you think about it, that your supposition that one seed might die is based on the assumption that both seeds were planted at the same time. However, if one seed receives the photon later than the other in a given frame, it was also planted later than the other, so it goes without light for the same length of time as the other seed.

If you want to understand relativity, it is essential that you anchor your thinking on the principle that an event is an event, so that if it happens in one frame it also happens in any other.